# Alternativa ao facade

Tags: java, design-pattern, uml

Gostaria de saber se tem algum design pattern ou alguma abordagem alternativa ao pattern facade.

Achei interessante a abordagem dele em criar uma "fachada" para um determinado "subsistema" porém a classe que deveria simplificar ficou enorme e um pouco confusa e suscetível a implementação de regras de negócios.

Imagina um subsistema com o dobro ou o tripo de classes

[image: Imagina um subsistema com o dobro ou o tripo de classes]

Tem algum padrão GOF ou alguma abordagem para acessar um subsistema de forma mais simplificada?

Comment: Sem você dar mais detalhes do que é o subsistema que você quer encapsular ou do porquê a classe ficou enorme, fica difícil indicar qual seria o melhor padrão para o seu caso.

Comment: O subsistema é bem genérico, falo da motivação do facade que é abstrair a complexidade de um sistema (que chamei de subsistema) para um cliente

Comment: Não precisa ser uma classe só, você pode (talvez deva) criar um conjunto de Facades.

Comment: @bfavaretto entendi, é uma boa abordagem pra diminuir a complexidade